# Scottish Mortality Register (Montrose 1787)

Tags: death-records, scotland, transcriptions

Before the introduction of the Statutory Registers there was no systematic record of deaths in Scotland. What there are are often financial in nature, recording the hire of the parish mort cloth or whatever.

The attached image is a page from the Parish Mortuary Register of Montrose, Angus for part of the year 1787. It really consists of two half pages, and each of these is divided (I think) into 8 columns

col 1 Month, but with occasional annotation /

col 2 Day of Month

col 3 Forename

col 4 Surname

col 5 ?

col 6 ?

col 7 ?

col 8 ?

The first entry to column 5 seems to be to be "buried", and all the others are "do", or ditto.

The first entry to column 6 I cannot read, the second I read as "Poor", then many dittos.

The first entry to column 7 seems to be "B"; on the left half page there are no entries, but on the right hand page there are entries "S***" and "C***" that I cannot read.

The first entry to column 8 seems to be "M"; in this column on the left hand page appear the words from column 7 on the right hand page, also a word "B***"; as well as "Child" and many dittos.

Can anyone read the words I cannot transcribe? and say what they signify?

[image: Montrose Mortality Register 1787]